# SDK location not found in Opentok-Chat-sample Code

Tags: android, android-studio, opentok, tokbox

I have downloaded **"Opentok chat sample"** code from github and i opened project in android studio.But i got below compilation error.

> ```
>  "SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable."
> ```

While i have set `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable.
and also i set sdk.dir in local.properties file.
How i resolve this error?

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

**Close project**
Close the current project and you'll be pop up with dialog, then proceed  to Configure option.

Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure -> SDKs on left column -> Android SDK Home Path -> give the exact path as you did on local.properties and select Valid Target.

Comment: delete old project and import project from new workspace location

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but suggestion,

its not the problem with your SDK location,
Build the new project by copying the res and src folder to your project, That works

Comment: Ok, i will try this.